# Numerically solving equations with expectations

Tags: numerical-methods, matlab, expectation

I have a equation $\mathbb{E}_\theta f(x,\theta)=a$, where $\theta$ is a vector real random variable with a known distribution, $a$ is a real constant, $x$ is a real (can be vector valued) variable. The function $f$ is too complex in $\theta$ for me to find a closed form expectation thus removing $\theta$.

One way to solve this is to set a value to $x$ and compute expectation using monte-carlo method and then increment or decrement $x$ and redo... I know that the function $f$ is monotonic in $x$ so the above method works. Is there some other, possibly easier way to solve it numerically? I am using Matlab and it would be great if there is existing function that I can use where I input $f$ and CDF of $\theta$ and it outputs solution.

Comment: Is $f$ differentiable with respect to $x$? If so then you can inform your step size using derivative information, which will accelerate convergence relative to other methods (at the cost of increased time spent per step). In any case, do you have an interval where you know the solution is? If so, then bisection is probably reasonably fast, assuming your Monte Carlo iterations converge reasonably fast. In any case, as stated I think this problem is too general to give a good answer. It might help to give some properties of $f$.

Comment: @Ian Thanks, differentiable in $x$ and has a finite interval too, so I will search in bisection over $x$ as adviced. However I don't understand what you meant by "assuming Monte Carlo converge fast"? I fix $x$ generate $N$ instances of $\theta$, where $N=10^6$ and then take naive sum(f)/N. Is there another way to do Monte Carlo?

Comment: How do you know that $N=10^6$ gives a sufficiently good estimate of the expectation? The usual approach is to work until your estimate of the variance (either from the running sample variance or an analytical estimate) is below some tolerance, not to use a fixed number of samples.

Answer (score 0):

Monte-Carlo functions are quite easy to create, I don't think some special-made function will help you out too much. Thus, similar to what was suggested, what you can to do is create a function that takes x as an input and performs the numerical integration. Call this function $exp\_mean(x)$.

$exp\_mean(x)=E_{\theta}[f(x,\theta)] - a$

(Hint: If possible, take the draws outside of the function so that you do not need to re-draw values every time the function is called). Then, use one of the non-linear solvers to solve for x such as fsolve.

x = fsolve('exp_mean',x0)

where x0 is some starting value. Try experimenting with different values for the number of draws and starting values. (I always prefer to do a grid search to obtain starting values).